# Silverlight XamlReader generating datatemplate ends with System.Type error

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I have this method call:

```
        public DataTemplate Create(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        string str = @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"" xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:MyProjectName;assembly:MyProjectName""><StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal""><TextBlock Text=""{Binding propertyLabel}"" FontStyle=""Italic"" Width=""120"" /><TextBox Text=""{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainPage}, Path=DataContext.Value1}"" Width=""120"" /></StackPanel></DataTemplate>";
        DataTemplate _dt =  (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(str);

        return _dt;
    }
```

On calling this i get the next error:
Line: 56
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2512
Category: ParserError
Message: Failed to create a 'System.Type' from the text 'local:MainPage'.
File:
Line: 1
Position: 253

Scenario is this:

Grid -> DataContext = ViewModel
ListBox -> ItemsSource = ViewModel.MyCollection
ListBoxItem -> DataTemaplate contains { ViewModel.MyCollection.propertyLabel and ViewModel.Value1 }

What's going on? Why do I get this error? Any ideas are very welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also couldn't get past this problem using the 'clr-namespace:...' namespace declaration. What I had to do was to declare an xml definition mapping in my code by using the XmlnsDefintionAttribute. A convenient place to put this attribute is in AssemblyInfo.cs. Do not put it inside a namespace block.

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition(
  "http://www.yourcompany.com/yourproduct/yourcomponent", 
  "MyProductName")] // substitute with your own namespace
```

You then have to substitute the clr-namespace with the URL in 'xmlns:local' XML attribute (3rd line in the sample below)

```
string str = @"<DataTemplate 
  xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"" 
  xmlns:local=""http://www.yourcompany.com/yourproduct/yourcomponent"">
  <StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal"">
    <TextBlock Text=""{Binding propertyLabel}"" FontStyle=""Italic"" Width=""120"" />
      <TextBox 
        Text=""{Binding DataContext.Value1
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainPage} }"" 
        Width=""120"" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>";
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, i am in the process of checking out your example.

Comment: It worked! Sorry for the delay, I just put it into the larger scale project to make sure that it works and it DID! Thanks base2 :)